# how to make an image move whenever the cursor hovers near the edge of the screen

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, move, slide

I need to do this project for school and I'm missing this one thing. I'm working in actionscript3 and have a panoramic picture of a room, that I'd like to move/slide(left and right) whenever the mouse cursor hovers near the edge of the screen. I'd also like to loop that image, so that you could slide it for eternity :)

I tried to find a script for that but apparently the language barrier is too much for me.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the logic first then have a go at implementing it :)

First you need to set a container for you image , in order for this image to loop , you can add the same image

```
 - in front of the current image when the current image x > 0
 - after the current image when 
   image.x = - (image.width + stage.stageWidth )//in full screen
```

To test this you can set an enter frame event listener that would take care of moving the container x in one or the other direction

```
     //going right
     container.x += 10

     //going left
     container.x -= 10
```

So altogether, you would simply need two images and you keep swapping position as soon as one gets out of the screen.

When you got this part working, you need to work out the mouse position in reference to the container's position.

For instance , in order for the container to go right at the maximum speed, you would need the mouseX value to be close to 0, for the container not to move , the mouseX value should be equal to stage.stageWidth/2 , the centre of the screen,  and for the container to go left at the maximum speed, the mouseX value should be stage.stageWidth.

With that you just need to work out a formula that changes the speed as well as the direction of the container movement in relation to these values. the direction would change according to a positive or negative value and the speed would decrease or increase according to the distance of the mouse relative to the centre of the screen.

In your enter frame event listener you would then change to:

```
     container.x += speed;
```

This should help you get started ;)